# Can't remove rvm from root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, rvmrc

So I made the mistake of using `sudo` in rmv ruby, which created a lot of problems.

I finally removed rmv using `rmv implode`, and installed another ruby after installing rbenv, but the problems still persisted.

Finally on checking environment variables, I found:

```
rvm_prefix=/usr/share
MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0
rvm_bin_path=/usr/share/rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=/home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0
GEM_PATH=/home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0:/home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@global
rvm_path=/usr/share/rvm
MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0
```

These variables still exist, and are probably the reason for malfunctioning of gem commands like:

```
sudo bundle install
sudo: bundle: command not found
```

I have been stuck in this from morning. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
rvm implode
```

and then remove exported variables from below files

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
```

Comment: I followed the exact same steps, but I couldn't find any environment variables in .bashrc, .profile or .bash_profile. Since I used sudo sometimes for `bundle update`, I think I might have caused problem there.

Comment: exactly you should not use ```sudo```

Comment: I know I shouldn't have, but I learned the hard way. Do you have any solution?